# Conditionally add a tag to merge-commit using Azure DevOps and git

Tags: build, azure-devops, tags, pull-request

I would like to basically achive the very same thing you could achive while using the built in "tag-functionality" for build in Azure DevOps, with one exception.. I need to add a tag conditionally..
The basic idea is to evanluate if the SourceBranch for my PR starts with refs/heads/hotfix, and that the target branch is refs/heads/master, then I would like to tag the final merged commit with the tag "hotfix".

I started with something like this:

```
    name: PR-$(Rev:r)

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
  - job: Say_hello_to_my_little_friend
    steps:
      - pwsh: Write-Host "Hello little friend!" 
  - job: Tag_As_Hotfix
    condition: and( eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'],'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/hotfix'))
    steps:
      - pwsh: |
          git tag hotfix
          git push origin master
        displayName: Tag as hotfix
```

However.. I quickly reialized that the branch master doesnt exists, since during a PR Azure DevOps creates a temporary branch which it runs all the "checks" at.
And even if the above would have worked.. I assume another issue would be that the tag would end up on the commit previous to the actuall merge-commit (or am I wrong?)..
Any idea of how to add a tag conditionally to the merged-commit?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the build as the **Build validation** in Pull Request, the build will execute before completing the Pull Request. So it will not meet your requirements.

You could refer to this doc about [Branch Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation).

> Any idea of how to add a tag conditionally to the merged-commit?

Since the variable `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` and `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch` only exist in the Pull Request Trigger Build, you could try the following Settings to set the pipeline. Create two pipelines: Pipeline 1 and Pipeline 2.

In Pipeline 1 , you could set the  condition and use [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to trigger the pipeline 2.

In Pipeline 2, you could add an Environment in the Pipeline 2, and the Environment contains the check: Invoke Rest API to [check the status of the Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). If the API response meets the requirements(Pull Reuqest Status is completed), it will run the git command to add tag.

Here is my sample:

**Pipeline 1:**

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
  - job: Tag_As_Hotfix
    condition: and( eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'],'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test'))
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $token = "PAT"
          
          $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{VariableGroup ID}?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
          
          $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
          
          $JSON = @'
          {
             "variables": {
                 "id": {
                    "value": "$(SYSTEM.PULLREQUEST.PULLREQUESTID)"
               }
            },
            "type": "Vsts",
            "name": "New variable group 16-Nov"
          }
          '@
          
          $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PUT -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $token = "PAT"
          
          $url="https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{Project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0"
          
          $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
          
          $JSON = @'
          {
              "definition": {
                  "id": BuilddefinitionID
              }
          }
          '@
          
          $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

**Note:** You need to create a Variable Group to save the Pull Request ID. This id could be used in the `Invoke Rest API check`.

**Pipeline2:**

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    environment: 'API Test'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: |
              git tag hotfix
              git push origin master
```

**Environment:** **Pipelines -> Environemnts-> Approvals and checks -> Invoke Rest API**

[image]

**Variable Group:**

[image]

**Workflow**

Create Pull Request -> Trigger Pipeline 1 -> Trigger Pipeline2 and Update the ID in Variable Group -> Pipleline 2 check the Pull Request Status -> Run the command to Add Tag.